# Xamarin.Forms SQLiteExtensions Many-To-Many relationship not retrieveing

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm having an issue retrieving many-to-many relationships. I have the following structure,

```
public class Story {
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // foreground
    [ManyToMany(typeof(StoryForeground), "StoryId", "Stories", CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
    public List<ForegroundStored> Foregrounds { get; set; }
}

public class StoryForeground
{
    public int ForegroundStoredId { get; set; }
    public int StoryId { get; set; }
}

public class ForegroundStored
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ManyToMany(typeof(StoryForeground), "ForegroundStoredId", "Foregrounds", CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.CascadeRead, ReadOnly = true)]
    public List<Story> Stories { get; set; }
}
```

To store, I use the SQLiteExtensions,

```
var conn = await GetDatabaseConnection<Story>().ConfigureAwait(false);
await conn.InsertWithChildrenAsync(story).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

To retrieve,

```
var conn = await GetDatabaseConnection<Story>().ConfigureAwait(false);
            return await AttemptAndRetry(async () => await conn.GetAllWithChildrenAsync<Story>(recursive: true).ConfigureAwait(false));
```

When I store, I see tables Story, ForegroundStored and StoryForeground have appropriate values in SQLite database. However, when I retrieve Story list, my Foregrounds parameter in Story class is null.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First of all, `StoryForeground` class, `ForegroundStoredId` and `StoryId` lack of `[ForeignKey(typeof(xxxxx))]` attribute, for example, `ForegroundStoredId` should add attribute `[ForeignKey(typeof(ForegroundStored))]`, `StoryId` need add `[ForeignKey(typeof(Story))]`, Then If you used `SQLite-Net Extensions`, you can insert the data(many to many relationship) , use `db.UpdateWithChildren()`, get the data with `db.GetWithChildren<Story>()`, please read this article step by step.: https://www.codejourney.net/2017/05/sqlite-net-extensions-many-to-many-relationships/

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Well, if you take a look, I'm indeed using UpdateWithChildren and GetWithChildren. I'm just using InsertWithChildren since I'm inserting, and GetAllWithChildren since I'm retrieving a list. With regards to the StoryForeground comment, you can have this many-to-many relationship setup in two ways using SQLiteExtensions, one shown in my question and the other shown by the article. Unfortunately, neither works. The issue is not with INSERT but with GETALL.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Just to backup my code, https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/issues/80/manytomany-relationship-destination-must